# Laravel 5.7 (Blade) - Operador ternário em dois níveis não está funcionando

Tags: operadores, laravel-blade

O seguinte código funciona:

```
if($cc->is_removed){
    $status = 'Removed';
}
elseif (! $cc->isActive){
    $status = 'Inactive';
}
elseif ($cc->isActive){
    $status = 'Active';
}
```

e na mesma página o seguinte código usando operadores ternários não funciona: ele nunca entra no 'Removed'.

```
{{ $cc->is_removed ? 'Removed' : !$cc->isActive ? 'Inactive' : 'Active' }}
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seu erro é relacionado a não ter uma divisão de parênteses, veja uma forma de resolver isso:

```
{{ $cc->is_removed ? 'Removed' : (!$cc->isActive ? 'Inactive' : 'Active') }}
```

Isso talvez se dê a forma na qual o blade compila.

Comment: Funciona. Valeu!